# How to set a string value from a textbox's value

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to set a string from a TextBox value:

E.g.

```
private void testing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Set <string> = TextBox.Text

        }
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Are you trying to assign the TextBox.Text value to a string variable or create a Set<string> that includes the TextBox.Text?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the word set, and you can drop the declaration if the string is already declared.

```
string yourString = TextBox.Text;
```

Comment: You don't even need to say string you could use var yourstring = TextBox.Text

Answer (score 0):

```
private void testing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string textOfTextBox = ((TextBox) sender).Text;
   MessageBox.Show (textOfTextBox);
}
```